# "easy" shift/reduce conflict

Tags: bison, shift-reduce-conflict

I'm writing a parser.  My grammar includes a CLOSE verb for files, and takes as arguments any number of filenames separated by whitespace.  Or, it would, if bison didn't complain, and it does.

```
close:          CLOSE filenames
                ;
filenames:      NAME
        |       filenames NAME
                ;
```

The report output says the problem is in State 124:

```
State 124

  232 close: CLOSE filenames .
  234 filenames: filenames . NAME

    NAME  shift, and go to state 198

    NAME      [reduce using rule 232 (close)]
    $default  reduce using rule 232 (close)
```

Here, "close" (lowercase) describes the syntax for CLOSE, one of several verbs in the language.

This looks to me like a textbook example of a recursive definition.  It seems "obvious" to me that **filenames** should cause as many **NAMES** as appear to be shifted, and then reduced according to the "close" rule.

What am I missing?

Comment: For some reason, you missed showing the rest of the grammar, which would probably reveal why you have a conflict. The most likely explanation here is that `close` occurs in a context where the next token (from a different command) might be `NAME`, which would cause an ambiguity. (By the way, bison's `output` file contains your grammar with all of the extraneous stuff like actions stripped out, which is a lot easier to look at than your actual parser. But you have to add back precedence declarations if any to produce a complete grammar.)

Comment: Thank you. The actual grammar is too long to show here.  You're 100% right that `NAME` appears all over the place.  I thought what I posted was enough, because State 124 mentions only `close` and `filenames`, which I show in their entirety.

Comment: Sorry, it's not enough. If you don't want to paste the whole grammar, find a subset of it which bison accepts but with the same conflict. Note that State 124 also references other states explicitly and is the target of yet other states, and the context is important.

Comment: Otherwise, you'll just need to look for the way that `NAME` gets into `FOLLOW(close)`. That's not usually too difficult if you have the state diagram to search through, which you have and I don't. :-)

Comment: Thanks again. Just knowing that I have to raise my nose over the fence and look around at other states tells me that it's not that "easy".  I'm currently looking at 9 s/r conflicts and 2 r/r, and most of them involve NAME.